# Xamarin Android FCM Token invalid & not registered after some tries in Firebase Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Xamarin Android, while developing firebase push notification i followed all the methods and concepts as per the Firebase Documentation. Now, the token generated successfully, when i try to sent notification from the firebase console, it shows completed and i tried postman also it give success status:1 but after sometimes i tried to send notification, it gave the result like token id was invalid and not registered. Another important thing is at any situation, notification is not received in My device. How can i solve this?

Comment: Are you sending a notification targeting the single device? Does the notification send successfully if you send to all devices?

Comment: No, I just sending notification for targeting single device

Answer (score 0):

The device token will expire over time, so it may be that the token that previously worked, has now expired.

One solution to keep track of a device token is to check for the token and then persist it externally on the start up of the application.

```
const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        }
```

You can read about token refreshing here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

Comment: As per your answer, i have another application in my mobile. it has only one token along 2+yr, if you don't mind please explain, how it is possible? why that token still working. So, my point is why the device not receive the notification yet. Did you get my point? please give any solution

Comment: It is possible that the token was never refreshed in over 2 years. You can read about it here in this article https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

Comment: yes you're right, but I already read this documentation. In this case, i have many confusions like where the issue occurred. first, Token generated successfully, second firebase sent the notification also successfully, then why my device not receiving this notification. Please explain...

Comment: Just to confirm everything is correctly implemented on the client, if you send a notification from FCM to all devices, you receive it ok?

Comment: Sure. I will let you know, if all works fine. One more thing is, while i'm test in post man and pushtry.com, it returns the result like token was invalid/not registered even i'm not erase the app data/uninstall app. Why it happen?